# How to change Wagtail's default language?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, wagtail

I'm using headless Wagtail and want to change the default backend language to Portuguese (pt-pt).
Following [wagtail's docs](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/advanced_topics/i18n/#changing-the-primary-language-of-your-wagtail-installation):

```py
# settings.py

USE_I18N = True

LANGUAGE_CODE = "pt-pt"
```

Then why I try to publish a wagtail page I get the following error:

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: POST Request URL:
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/pages/11/edit/
>
> Django Version: 3.1.2 Python Version: 3.9.0 Installed Applications:
> ['home',  'search',  'news',  'about_us',  'product',  'dashboard',
> 'wagtail_headless_preview',  'wagtail.contrib.forms',
> 'wagtail.contrib.redirects',  'wagtail.embeds',  'wagtail.sites',
> 'wagtail.users',  'wagtail.snippets',  'wagtail.documents',
> 'wagtail.images',  'wagtail.search',  'wagtail.admin',
> 'wagtail.core',  'wagtail.api.v2',  'modelcluster',  'taggit',
> 'django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth',
> 'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions',
> 'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
> 'rest_framework',  'corsheaders'] Installed Middleware:
> ['django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
> 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
> 'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware']
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\diogo\OneDrive -
> Universidade de Tras-os-Montes e Alto
> Douro\Marfon\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
> line 52, in inner
> response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\diogo\OneDrive - Universidade de Tras-os-Montes e Alto
> Douro\Marfon\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
> line 195, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\diogo\OneDrive - Universidade de Tras-os-Montes e Alto
> Douro\Marfon\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py",
> line 49, in *wrapped_view_func
> response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\diogo\OneDrive - Universidade de Tras-os-Montes e Alto
> Douro\Marfon\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail-2.11rc1-py3.9.egg\wagtail\admin\urls_*init**.py",
> line 170, in wrapper
> return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\diogo\OneDrive - Universidade de Tras-os-Montes e Alto
> Douro\Marfon\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail-2.11rc1-py3.9.egg\wagtail\admin\auth.py",
> line 179, in decorated_view
> response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\diogo\OneDrive - Universidade de Tras-os-Montes e Alto
> Douro\Marfon\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py",
> line 85, in view
> return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\diogo\OneDrive - Universidade de Tras-os-Montes e Alto
> Douro\Marfon\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail-2.11rc1-py3.9.egg\wagtail\admin\views\pages\edit.py",
> line 138, in dispatch
> return super().dispatch(request)   File "C:\Users\diogo\OneDrive - Universidade de Tras-os-Montes e Alto
> Douro\Marfon\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py",
> line 116, in dispatch
> return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\diogo\OneDrive - Universidade de Tras-os-Montes e Alto
> Douro\Marfon\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail-2.11rc1-py3.9.egg\wagtail\admin\views\pages\edit.py",
> line 257, in post
> return self.form_valid(self.form)   File "C:\Users\diogo\OneDrive - Universidade de Tras-os-Montes e Alto Douro\Marfon\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail-2.11rc1-py3.9.egg\wagtail\admin\views\pages\edit.py",
> line 283, in form_valid
> return self.publish_action()   File "C:\Users\diogo\OneDrive - Universidade de Tras-os-Montes e Alto
> Douro\Marfon\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail-2.11rc1-py3.9.egg\wagtail\admin\views\pages\edit.py",
> line 329, in publish_action
> revision = self.page.save_revision(   File "C:\Users\diogo\OneDrive - Universidade de Tras-os-Montes e Alto
> Douro\Marfon\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail-2.11rc1-py3.9.egg\wagtail\core\models.py",
> line 1385, in save_revision
> self.full_clean()   File "C:\Users\diogo\OneDrive - Universidade de Tras-os-Montes e Alto
> Douro\Marfon\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail-2.11rc1-py3.9.egg\wagtail\core\models.py",
> line 1033, in full_clean
> super().full_clean(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\diogo\OneDrive - Universidade de Tras-os-Montes e Alto
> Douro\Marfon\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line
> 1390, in full_clean
> raise ValidationError(errors)
>
> Exception Type: ValidationError at /admin/pages/11/edit/ Exception
> Value: {'locale': ['locale instance with id 1 does not exist.']}

Any suggestion? Is there some extra step I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're following documentation from Wagtail 2.0, which is very outdated. The documentation for Wagtail 2.11's internationalisation support (unreleased at the time of writing) can be found here: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/advanced_topics/i18n.html

[As mentioned there](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/advanced_topics/i18n.html#configuring-available-languages), when you configure languages in your settings file you also need to set up Locale records in the database. This can be done in a data migration, or by enabling the `wagtail.locales` app and going through the Settings -> Locales area in the admin:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'wagtail.locales',
    # ...
]
```