# wagtail: Locale_ID cannot be null

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, wagtail

I'm trying to deploy a website with wagtail 2.11 on pythonanywhere. However, I'm unable to save any page models in the frontend.

The cause seems to be that in my 'home'-app, migration 0002_create_homepage.py cannot be not applied. Trying so gives me this error (IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'locale_id' cannot be null")):

```
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 243, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 121, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/special.py", line 190, in database_forwards
    self.code(from_state.apps, schema_editor)
  File "/home/yogagarten/yogagarten.pythonanywhere.com/home/migrations/0002_create_homepage.py", line 21, in create_homepage
    homepage = HomePage.objects.create(
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 447, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 789, in save_base
    parent_inserted = self._save_parents(cls, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 818, in _save_parents
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 895, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 933, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1254, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1397, in execute_sq
l
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wra
ppers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/yogagarten/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 78, in execute
    raise IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args))
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'locale_id' cannot be null")
```

My settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'wagtail.locales',
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de-DE'
LANGUAGES = [('de', 'German'),]
WAGTAILADMIN_PERMITTED_LANGUAGES = [('de', 'German'),]
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Basic model example:

```
class HomePage(Page):
    template = 'home/index.html'
    ueberschrift = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=False, null=True)
    content_panels = ([FieldPanel('ueberschrift')])

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Startseite'
```

I haven't created any page objects yet.

Can you give me some advice on how to fix this error? I understand that every page model comes with a locale field. But I don't know what to do with that info.

What I've tried:

- redid everything with a new database
- reset the language settings to default (en-us)
- I tried the [run_before](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/releases/2.11.html) command.
- I checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64600902/how-to-change-wagtails-default-language) and followed this part of
  the official [documentation](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/advanced_topics/i18n.html#configuring-available-languages)

I'm using wagtail 2.11 with django 3.1.3 and python 3.8.

Thanks so much!

Comment: The `run_before` fix really ought to solve this. After you added this, did the output of `manage.py migrate` show the `wagtailcore.0053_locale_model` migration happening before home.0002_create_homepage?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @gasman. No, it doesn't. When I run run_before, I get the error `django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration wagtailcore.0053_locale_model is applied before its dependency hom
e.0002_create_homepage on database 'default'`. Can it be linked to the fact that I chose German as the default language instead of English?

Comment: With the `run_before` line in place, try dropping and recreating the database (I'm assuming you don't have any data that needs keeping yet...) before re-running `manage.py migrate`. This is necessary because the database will be in an inconsistent state following the previous failed run (the one without run_before).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the following line to the 0002_create_homepage.py migration file, inside `class Migration`:

```
run_before = [
    ('wagtailcore', '0053_locale_model'),
]
```

This change is necessary as a result of the new multi-language implementation in Wagtail 2.11. More details are here: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/releases/2.11.html#run-before-declaration-needed-in-initial-homepage-migration

If you've already run `./manage.py migrate` without this new line in place and received the locale_id IntegrityError, you'll need to drop and recreate the database and then re-run `./manage.py migrate`, as the previous failure will have left the database in an inconsistent state. (Dropping and recreating the database will delete any existing data, but as this issue will only arise on a new deployment on a clean database anyway, that shouldn't be an issue.)

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a lot, @gasman! I added the run_before command after my first migrate - this caused the error.

Comment: Those using pytest, remember to recreate the database (`pytest --create-db`).